# How to lock the position of a cytoscape.js node within its parent node

Tags: cytoscape.js

I want to lock the position of a node relative to its parent compound node, such that if I grab and drag the parent node, the child node moves with it, but the child is not individually grabbable.  If I set the child to be ungrabbable and/or locked, then it doesn't move with its parent, but if I don't, it can be individually dragged, which I don't want.  Can this be done?

Failing that, is there a way to programmatically grab/ungrab a node so that I can listen for a grab event and then grab the parent instead/as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compound grabbing/locking logic with children probably needs to be improved in general, but you should be able to achieve the effect you want today with the current version:

```
cy.nodes().nonorphans()
  .on('grab', function(){ this.ungrabify(); })
  .on('free', function(){ this.grabify(); })
;
```

This makes all nonorphan/child nodes not directly grabbable but still moveable with their parents.

Ref for improvements : https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/1074

Comment: This works, but as we discussed in email, I'd rather have the child be able to pass its grab on to its parent, rather than just have the child grab be a no-op.  Consider this a feature request for a programmatic grab or equivalent.

Comment: In >=2.5, you can use `events: no` to disable events (including grabbing) on elements.

Answer (score 4):

For posterity, the code that will do this in [cytoscape-automove](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-automove)

```
let nodeList = cy.nodes().nonorphans();
for (let i=0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {
        let n = nodeList[i];
        let parent = n.parent()[0];
        let family = parent.children();
        family.add(parent);

        this.cy.automove({
            nodesMatching: family,
            reposition: 'drag',
            dragWith: n
        });
    }
```