# Grab compound nodes when a child node is grabbed cytoscape.js

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, cytoscape.js

**How To drag parent/compound node when drag on child node**

In my case I have some child node inside compound node, I want to make child node not individually movable and want to move the whole components when drag on node.
In my example everything working fine as i expected like drag on parent node move the whole components but drag on child not not move the parent node along with is child node.

> Gone throw the following links for my related question.

[Grab compound nodes when a child node is grabbed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34785598/grab-compound-nodes-when-a-child-node-is-grabbed)
[Improved compound lock/grab/drag behaviour cytoscape](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/1074)

[How to lock the position of a cytoscape.js node within its parent node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32130023/how-to-lock-the-position-of-a-cytoscape-js-node-within-its-parent-node/32406098#32406098)

set the style property `events:no` to child node remove the drag event of child node and working as i expected but it remove all events in child node. but i need tab event to my child node. only i want to disable drag event in child node for its working correct.

> How to remove/disable drag event to the child node and only allow to
>   parent node or any other option to resolve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you want events to fall through (i.e. bubble up without emitting on the target itself), then you can't really do this selectively for higher level gestures.

You can implement the behaviour you want by just moving along all the siblings when a child is dragged.  The visual effect is the same.

Comment: How to move compound node along with all child when its child node dragged. can you please help me with example code?